# Howto map Ctrl + Numeric Home/End to Beginning/End of Document in TextMate

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-snow-leopard, textmate

I really REALLY want to map these keys as specified in the title, but I cant find out how to do it.

My aim is to get the keyboard as close to Windows as possible since its hard to un-learn 25+ years of experience with that layout. I have managed to get 95% as I want it, but I cant get this last bit to work.

I have put this is in ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

```
{   
    "^\UF729" = "moveToBeginningOfDocument:";
    "^\UF72B" = "moveToEndOfDocument:"; 
}
```

It works with the regular Home/End keys, but not with those on the numeric keyboard.

I'm also using KeyRemap4MacBook, which solves a lot but not everything.

Can anyone help with this? A bonus question is why the new layout is ignore in some applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys in your snippet are the regular `home` and `end` keys. Don't you think it's a good thing that it doesn't work with other keys than the ones you have specified?

I am not 100% sure but I think that Mac OS X doesn't support this "numeric keys as navigation keys" business at all, at least natively.

If you want to remap the `7` and the `1` from the numeric keypad you will have to add two more lines to `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` for these two keys.

As for your bonus question: your custom keybindings only affect Cocoa apps. You can't really expect Java/GTK/QT/Whatever-based applications to respect them. Apps by Adobe/Microsoft are serious offenders in this regard. What other applications do you have troubles with? Hell, even Apple has been slow at adopting their own dog food (Finder, iTunes).

Comment: I found a good app that solved almost all of my problems, its called KeyBindingsEditor from bitart.

Comment: As the saying goes: "there's an app for that".